# Calculating sample size from a distribution with an unknown mean

Tags: statistics

I'm trying to read through DeGroot's *Probability and Statistics* and my progress has slowed in Chapter 7. DeGroot makes the following definition:

For any random variable $Z = g(X_1, ..., X_n) $, we shall let $ E_\theta(Z) $ denote the expectation of Z calculated with respect to the joint p.d.f. or joint p.f. $ f_n(\mathbf{x} | \theta) $. Thus if $f_n(\mathbf{x} | \theta) $ is a p.d.f.,

$$ E_\theta(Z) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \cdot\cdot\cdot\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(\mathbf{x})f_n(\mathbf{x} | \theta) ~ dx_1 \cdot\cdot\cdot dx_n$$

In other words, $E_\theta(Z)$ is the expectation of $Z$ for a given value of $\theta ~\epsilon~ \Omega$. Now consider the following exercises:

> 1. Suppose that a random sample is to be taken from a normal distribution for which the value of the mean $\theta$ is unknown and the standard deviation is $2$. How large a random sample must be taken in order that $E_\theta(|\bar{X}_n - \theta|^2) \leq 0.1 $ for every possible value of $\theta$?
> 2. For the conditions of Exercise 1, how large a random sample must be taken in order that $E_\theta(|\bar{X}_n - \theta|) \leq 0.1 $ for every possible value of $\theta$?

The solution to exercise 2 reads:

Once again, $ \bar{X}_n $ has the normal distribution with mean $\theta$ and variance $4 /n$. Hence, the random variable $ Z = (\bar{X}_n - \theta) / (2 / \sqrt{n})$ will have the standard normal distribution. Therefore,

$$ E_\theta(|\bar{X}_n - \theta|) = {2 \over \sqrt{n}} E_\theta( | Z|) = {2 \over \sqrt{n}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty |z| {1\over \sqrt{2\pi}} e^{- {z^2 \over 2}} dz = 2 \sqrt{{2 \over {n\pi}}} $$

From which the problem can be finished in the obvious way. My confusion arises at the second equality in the computations above, namely the implication that:

$$  E_\theta( |Z|) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty |z| {1\over \sqrt{2\pi}} e^{- {z^2 \over 2}} dz $$

which seems (in my mind) to directly contradict the definition of $ E_\theta(Z)$ provided above. I don't know what theorem I'm forgetting from multivariable calculus that establishes the equivalence of these integrations.

Some clarity here would be very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I've realized one mistake that was causing me confusion. To get a sense of the problem I was considering the case $ n = 2 $, and so proceeding naively from the definition I wrote:

\begin{align} 
E_\theta(|\bar{X}_2 - \theta|) &= {\int\int}_{\Bbb{R}^2} \left ({x_1 + x_2} \over 2 \right) f_2(x_1, x_2 | \theta)~ dA \\
&= {1 \over 2} {\int\int}_{\Bbb{R}^2} [x_1 f(x_1 | \theta)]\cdot f(x_2 | \theta) + [x_2 f(x_2 | \theta)]\cdot f(x_1 | \theta) ~dx_1 dx_2 \\
&= {1 \over 2} \int_\Bbb{R} \left( \int_\Bbb{R} [x_1 f(x_1 | \theta)]\cdot f(x_2 | \theta)~ dx_1 + \int_\Bbb{R} [x_2 f(x_2 | \theta)]\cdot f(x_1 | \theta)~ dx_1 \right) ~ dx_2 \\
&= {1 \over 2} \int_\Bbb{R} \left( f(x_2 | \theta)\cdot \int_\Bbb{R} [x_1 f(x_1 | \theta)]~ dx_1 + [x_2 f(x_2 | \theta)]\cdot \int_\Bbb{R}f(x_1 | \theta)~ dx_1 \right) ~ dx_2 \\
&= {1 \over 2} \int_\Bbb{R} f(x_2 | \theta)\cdot E(X_1) + [x_2 f(x_2 | \theta)] \cdot 1 ~dx_2 \\
&= {1 \over 2} \left[ E(X_1) \cdot \int_\Bbb{R} f(x_2 | \theta) ~dx_2 + \int_\Bbb{R} x_2 f(x_2 | \theta) ~dx_2 \right ] \\
&= {1 \over 2} \left [E(X_1) \cdot 1 + E(X_2) \right] \\ 
&= \theta
\end{align}

I now realize there are at least 2 mistakes being made:

1. I neglected absolute values
2. I neglected $\theta$!

Specifically, I should've started with:

$$ E_\theta (|\bar{X}_n - \theta|) = {\int\int}_{\Bbb{R}^2} \left |{{x_1 + x_2} \over 2}  - \theta \right| f_2(x_1, x_2 | \theta)~ dA $$

and proceeded this way, but this integrand makes me want to find an alternative approach

I was browsing around SE looking for inspiration, and another problem got me thinking about the expression 
$$ P[ (\bar{X}_n - \theta ) \leq c\sigma ]  = P \left[ {\left( \bar{X}_n - \theta \over {\sigma}\right )} \leq c  \right] = P(Z \leq c) = \Phi(c) $$

I think this means that if $F$ is the c.d.f. of the variable $ \bar{X}_n - \theta $, then $F(x) = \Phi(x / \sigma) $, which justifies switching to the standard normal variable to compute $ E_\theta(|Z|) $.